# TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid() Function Uint16 Parameter?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-ttf

While normal ttf render functions take const char* for the text they're gonna render TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid() function takes const Uint*.

I used this structure to create textures from ttf surfaces while working with ASCII characters:

```
Text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(times, title.c_str(), MakeColor(255, 0, 255));
ButtonTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Text);
```

.

And when I wanted to work with unicode I tried this:

```
Text = TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid(times, title.c_str(), MakeColor(255, 0, 255));
ButtonTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Text);
```

.

Because title.c_str() is const char* and the function wants const Uint16 I can't create the texture.

This is how I pass the title:

```
MenuButtons[0] = new CreateButton("TEXT");

void CreateButton(string title)
{
   Text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(times, title.c_str(), MakeColor(255, 0, 255));
   ButtonTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Text);
    //or
   Text = TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid(times, title.c_str(), MakeColor(255, 0, 255));
   ButtonTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Text);
}
```

**Question: How can I convert my string to Uint16?**

Comment: What is in `title` in the second case? If it's not Unicode, why are you using the Unicode function?

Comment: It's unicode, I want my program to be able to render characters like "ç,ş,ü,ğ,ı" which ASCII doesn't have.

Comment: Please give more information on this. Where does `title` come? Is it utf-8, ascii or e.g. latin-1 text?

Comment: I edited my code. I want it to support latin2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen two  versions of `TTF_RenderText_Solid`. One supports `utf-8`, one supports `latin1`. When your version supports `utf-8` you simply need a string where the text is encoded in this format. `utf-8` and `latin-1` use a simple `char` as storage unit so you need to look that up in the documentation to know that. Let's assume your version supports `latin1` then it covers more characters than your expected `ascii` character range.

However, that is still not what you want then.  So when you want to use `TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid` your text-producer must deliver `UTF-16` characters. So you need to know where the content from `title` comes from and how it's encoded.

For a fast example you can try static text (with a c++11 compiler):

```
const Uint16 text[]=u"Hello World! \u20AC";
```

This should also help: 
[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: const Uint16 text[]=u"Hello World! \u20AC"; when I type this I get the following errors: initialisation with {...} is expected for aggregate object and expected a ';'

Comment: It gives the error Utf16Char is undefined. I also moved my project to vs2012 but I still get the same error

Comment: It works but I get really strange character instead of hello

Comment: Why do you accept the answer then? I need more information to help you out.

Comment: Do you get a "H" when you use this string? `const Uint16 text[]=u"\u4800";`?

Comment: I don't think vs2012 supports that kind of code. I can't use u before " ".