# Can't compile C++11 code on VS2012

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2012

I had a project I had built on VC++ 2010 Express. I updated the project to VS2012 but I can't compile the following c++11 code:

```
const Uint16 text[]=u"Hello World! \u20AC";
```

I get the errors:

Initialization with {...} expected for aggregrate object and

expected a';'

What's the cause of this and how can I correct this errors?

Comment: The type you are looking for is `char16_t`.

Comment: I tried it . Gives the same error.

Comment: My guess would be, you used to build with [`/Zc:wchar_t-`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh8che7s.aspx) and are now building without. You are trying to initialize an array of, probably, `unsigned short`s with a sequence of `wchar_t`s. This is only possible under `/Zc:wchar_t-` (which makes `wchar_t` a typedef for `unsiged short`, rather than a distinct fundamental type as is proper). Why are you using `Uint16` and not `wchar_t` for text anyway? Your code is not, in fact, valid C++ (assuming `Uint16` is a typedef for `unsigned short`)

Comment: It was recommended to me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413086/ttf-renderunicode-solid-function-uint16-parameter/32413306?noredirect=1#comment52697895_32413306. But I tried char16_t too. It gives the same error

Comment: Unicode string literals have been introduced in *VS2015*. So the `u` string literal prefix shouldn't be available in neither VS2010 nor VS2012.

Comment: How can I do the same thing in vs2012